# Impossible to install jshint-eclipse plugin

Tags: javascript, eclipse, ide, jshint

It is impossible to install jshint-eclipse plugin (http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/), the following error occurs:

```
No repository found at http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/updates/
```

Maybe, somebody knows another way to install this plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click `Help > Install New Software..`

Use the proper update site link. i.e "http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/updates". Observe that there is no **"/"** at the end.

I installed successfully this plugin on eclipse kepler.

Refer below screen-shots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have installed it successfully